# can some one help to fit the array in kmeans clustering

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, k-means

when i try to fit it in kmeans clustering it throws error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(df)
```

Array decription.
Name: Vector, Length: 179, dtype: object

0       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...

1       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...

10      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...

100     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...

101     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your column has a list in it. It needs to be opened up into multiple columns before passing it to KMeans.

```
df = pd.read_json('/Users/roshansk/Downloads/NewsArticles.json')

#Extracting the vectors into columns
vectors = df.Vector.apply(pd.Seriesies)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(vectors)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `df.head` to your question. It would make it easier for me to write the code then

Comment: here is the data set https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hv7lxzSBKdGHwwvPBoGHxOTMvqlbNWD9/view?usp=sharing